# How to make unique constraint on ONE to MANY relationship?

Tags: database, postgresql, orm, nestjs, typeorm

I have two entities: `project` and `actor`.

```
export abstract class BaseEntityModel {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;
}

@Entity()
export class Project extends BaseEntityModel {
    @Column()
    title: string;

    @OneToMany(type => Actor, actor => actor.project)
    @JoinColumn()
    actors: Actor[];
}

@Entity()
export class Actor extends BaseEntityModel {
    @Column({unique: true}) 
    title: string;

    @ManyToOne(type => Project, project => project.actors)
    project: Project;
}
```

I want unique actor title per project, but not across database.

#### OK

```
projects: [
  {
    title: "webapp",
    actors: [
      {
        title: "dev"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    title: "json-parser",
    actors: [
      {
        title: "dev"
      },
      {
        title: "target"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

#### NOT OK

```
projects: [
  {
    title: "webapp",
    actors: [
      {
        title: "dev"
      },
      {
        title: "dev"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    title: "json-parser",
    actors: [
      {
        title: "dev"
      },
      {
        title: "target"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

`@Column({unique: true})` work as unique across table, that is not what I want. There is also class decorator `@Unique(['title'])`, but it seems to be doing the same.

Is there something from TypeORM that I can use, or do I have to check myself if the `actor.title` already exist in project. To avoid duplicated `actor.title` in the same project. While keeping the possibility to have multiple time the same `actor.title` across the database?

Note that `Actor` entity should not be shared across `projects` (no many to many relationship).

Answer (score 6):

Adding `@Unique(['title', 'project'])` class decorator to `Actor` seems to be what I was looking for, note that I had "corrupted" my database somehow and migration worked correctly only after deleting/creating it.